# Build with parameters for GitHub organization

Tags: jenkins-plugins, jenkins-pipeline, jenkins-cli

Is there a way we can add build with parameter option in jenkins for github organization project??

Appreciate for your answeres.

[image: something like this]

Comment: What did you mean by github org project ? Are you able to elaborate on what you are trying to achieve ?

Comment: I assume that it is automatically built and some information from the web hook used as parameter?

Answer (score 2):

First, if you're using the GitHub Organization - It is deprecated and hasn't been updated in 2 years.

https://plugins.jenkins.io/github-organization-folder

So you might want to consider using the Multi Branch Pipeline (MBP) in conjunction with Job DSL instead.

Next - the idea is that the MBP is dynamically creating branch 'jobs' when it scans the repo you provide.  I'm not sure that you can't put a parameter block in the pipeline you create, but if you did and it worked, I wonder if the job can be automatically triggered.

https://jenkins.io/doc/book/pipeline/syntax/#parameters